# using file config message in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would use a message file to various warnings that are given to the user, use a file msg.js

```
var mensaje = {
        DATOS_VACIOS : "Verifique los campos ...."
}
```

call

```
alert(mensaje.DATOS_VACIOS);
```

I wonder if anyone knows a way to do better, or that involves having this object in memory, if it can degrade performance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it depends on the client, but unless you have a huge list of messages (1MB or more), loading msg.js into memory won't affect performance. It is better to do it the way you already are because the messages will be available to the user virtually instantly. If you want to hold less in memory, you could split up msg.js into smaller files and load them asynchronously, destroying the old object each time. Doing so would make the browser store less, but it would translate into much slower response time. Not worth it unless your msg.js is huge.

Comment: if I want to avoid bringing them asynchronously, and the file will be fairly large, as is the first to do this I wanted to hear opinions, thank you very much.

Comment: One thing you could do is minify your messages: http://jscompress.com/